# Setup aliasdomains to wordpress multisite

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mapping, multisite

I have the following goal but can't seem to get it to work.

**I have a Wordpress multisite setup on one domain like**

- abc.com (main)
- abc.com/2
- abc.com/3

I seem to be able to set def.com to abc.com/2  but how do I keep the url intact?

**My goal is to have it like this**

- abc.com -> abc.com
- abc.com/2 -> def.com
- abc.com/3 -> ghi.com

Thnx for your time!

** EDIT **
I guess maybe the solution for this lies in my .htaccess file ?

Comment: Do you have access to cpanel?

Comment: I do have access yes but not really sure if I have the rights to change anything. Could the problem be solved there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might check WPMUDEV's Domain Mapping plugin. Basically you will do the mapping inside your Network rather than inside the CPANEL for the CNAMEs of the subsites.